# How can I build a soap client in HTML5 that doesn’t expose its username and password?

Tags: html, soap

I'm looking into building an HTML5 application for a soap API that I use. The problem lies in that I don't where to start on this.

I'm aware that you can build a soap client using JavaScript but then the username and password would be viewable to anyone and that's just silly.

Suggestions please

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want the credentials to be visible to the end user you will have to use a server side language as well.

I know html5 sounds like it can do everything, but it is pretty limited when it comes to communicating to other sources. A webapp will still rely on server side languages!

Comment: Oh in that case it should be quite trivial, I think. Off to learn html5. Thanks